# How get url from database and show it in a iframe page

Tags: php, iframe

That's a simple script to adult content site I'd make with pieces of another codes. I am not a expertin PHP! I just can understand the basic.

```
<html>

<body>

<div align="center">

<div align="center" id="box">

   <div align="center" id="carrosel">


<?php

$quantidade = 64;

$pagina     = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;

$inicio     = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM teen ORDER BY RAND() ASC LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";

$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)){

?>
```

So, my problem is here. In that way, when you click the thumb, the browser will open that url that is out my site. the idea is to embed the video on a new iframe page. Someone can help me?

```
<a href="<?php echo $ln['url_video'];?>"target="_blank">
    <img src="<?php echo    $ln['thumb_video'];?>" /></a>


<?php           



}



?>


<div align="center">

<?php   

$sqlTotal = "SELECT thumb FROM teen";

$qrTotal  = mysql_query($sqlTotal) or die(mysql_error());

$numTotal = mysql_num_rows($qrTotal);

$totalPagina= ceil($numTotal/$quantidade);



            for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPagina; $i++){

        if($i == $pagina)

            echo $i;

        else



            echo "<a href=\"?pagina=$i\">$i</a> ";



    }

?>

</div><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is basic HTML and isn't affected by PHP. Just use an iframe instead of an anchor tag. That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` to print your links

```
while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)){
echo '<a href='.$ln['url_video'].'target="_blank">',
     '<img src='.$ln['thumb_video'].'/></a>';
}
```

And I found one more thing replace your `echo "<a href=\"?pagina=$i\">$i</a> ";` with this:

```
echo '<a href="some.php?pagina='.$i.'">$i</a>';
```

And one more thing, use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`

Comment: Thanks folks, but doesn't work! when I change the "while" above, the thumbs disappears! I think I need make one array with the url and and "transfer" that array to another page and embed the url into one iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use window.open function, it will open the video in a new popup,

```
<a href="Javascript:;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $ln['url_video'];?>',
'View Video')" ><img src="<?php echo $ln['thumb_video'];?>" /></a>
```

More details for window.open at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp